# How to convert date::year_month_day to chrono time_point

Tags: c++, datetime, c++-chrono

I am trying to convert `date::year_month_day` of Mr. Howard Hinnant's library to a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`, but had no success. Ultimately, I want to calculate `time_since_epoch().count()` from the time point in the UTC timezone.

My code below kind of does the job (the result is in my local time zone) but preferrably I would like to use `date` library for this if it offers such functionalities.

```cpp
    date::year_month_day _ymd = date::year{2023}/11/9; // November 9, 2023

    // Modern C++
    // The following returns 16994880000000000
    // = Thursday, July 16, 1970 4:48:00 PM, which is not 2023/11/09
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp = 
            std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::days>(std::chrono::sys_days{_ymd});

    // Classic C++
    // The following returns 1702108800
    // = Saturday, December 9, 2023 8:00:00 AM, which of course is not 2023/11/09
    struct tm t = {0};
    t.tm_year = _ymd.year().operator int() - 1900;
    t.tm_mon = _ymd.month().operator unsigned int();
    t.tm_mday = _ymd.day().operator unsigned int();
    time_t timeSinceEpoch = mktime(&t);
    std::cout << "timeSinceEpoch " << timeSinceEpoch << "\n"; // it will be in my time zone, not UTC
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I notice you're using Windows.  Recent versions of MSVC ship with a full implementation of C++20 `<chrono>`.  This obsoletes my date lib.  My recommendation is to use C++20 `<chrono>`.  Though if for some reason you can't, I'm happy to help.

Your first try is correct.  But for some reason it seems incorrect to you:

```
date::year_month_day _ymd = date::year{2023}/11/9; // November 9, 2023

// Modern C++
// The following returns 16994880000000000
// = Thursday, July 16, 1970 4:48:00 PM, which is not 2023/11/09
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp = 
        std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::days>(std::chrono::sys_days{_ymd});
```

Windows `system_clock::time_point` counts in ticks of 1/10 of a microsecond (decimicroseconds).  And 16994880000000000 of those ticks is 2023-11-09 00:00:00.0000000 UTC.  From your comments you appear to be interpreting 16994880000000000 as a count of nanoseconds instead of decimicroseconds.  It would help if you show the code that interprets 16994880000000000 for you.

Though your code is correct, it is also overly verbose.  With no change in functionality it can be simplified to:

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp = std::chrono::sys_days{_ymd};
```

The type `sys_days` is a type alias for `time_point<system_clock, days>`. So you've effectively just inserted a gratuitous copy construction.

If you *want* the result as a count of nanoseconds, that too is easily done:

```
std::chrono::sys_time<std::chrono::nanoseconds> tp = std::chrono::sys_days{_ymd};
```

Now `tp.time_since_epoch().count()` is 1699488000000000000 (two more zeroes on the end).

Comment: I am developing for both Windows and Linux. I have C++20 in both OS, but my GCC11 does not have C++20 with date libraries in chrono. In my `CMakeLists.txt`, I have `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)` but still my GCC in `/opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/bin/gcc` complains about using the namespace `chrono` for date libraries.

Comment: Ok.  Linux's `system_clock::time_point` has precision `nanoseconds`. I'm guessing that's how you misinterpreted 16994880000000000: by passing it from Windows to Linux.  If you use `date::sys_time<std::chrono::nanoseconds>` on both platforms (in place of `system_clock::time_point`)  that will solve that problem.

Comment: Thank you. I have the latest devtoolset for CentOS7, gcc11, I thought it would have the std::chrono date library. May I ask what compiler you personally prefer to use in linux?

Comment: Except for online compilers, I don't use Linux.  However I can tell you that when gcc-14 ships, it will include the complete C++20 `<chrono>` library.

Comment: May I ask if you could share the link to online compilers?

Comment: Here's a good one for Linux: https://wandbox.org/permlink/RBz9k4XnHlw5OYY9

Comment: Thank you very much for giving back to the community. Really appreciate all your great work, Mr. Hinnant.